# Inject generic parameters with structuremap 2.6

Tags: dependency-injection, structuremap

I need to inject generic repositories (IRepository) into my classes' constructors but I dont know how to do it with the new DSL in structuremap 2.6, does anyone know how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with just one line of code in your configuration.  Assuming you have this:

Entities:
- Customer
- Order

And have a generic repository model like this:

- Repository : IRepository

And have a app services that look like:

```
public AppService(IRepository<Customer> custRepo, IRepository<Order> orderRepo)
```

You would have something like this.  Notice the bit about using the scanner to hook up your custom repositories.

```
public class SmRegistry : Registry
    {
        public SmRegistry()
        {
            For(typeof (IRepository<>))
                .Use(typeof (Repository<>));

            //using this will find any custom repos, like CustomerRepository : Repository<Customer>
            //Scan(scanner =>
            //         {
            //             scanner.TheCallingAssembly();
            //             scanner.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof (IRepository<>));

            //         });
        }
    }
```

Assuming your Repositories are defined in some other assembly from your application, you can use Registries to hook it all together.  Check out this post:

http://blog.coreycoogan.com/2010/05/24/using-structuremap-to-configure-applications-and-components/